# is a search for nearest places possible in gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

just wondering if i can search for places near to a specific lat/lang with gmaps4rails. I checked the code but did not find anything. if sbd. does somebody already implemented sth like this ?

like (taken from geocoder gem):

```
 Place.near([40.71, 100.23], 20)
```

thx

Comment: why not use both gems? geocoder gem is awesome

Comment: yeah, just did that :) i thought gmaps4rails would be an replacement. but it seems it works great with both gems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made `gmaps4rails` and do not want it to be a copy of what exists and works perfectly.

So keep on using `Geocoder` or [Geokit](https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3) for search, `gmaps4rails`is here to display stuff :)

Basically, answer is no!